# GA4 - BigQuery links "Link" button is greyed out when exporting second instance

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Questions on GA4, I have access to a GA4 account and I already export the one GA4 instance data to BigQuery by using the "BigQuery links" option. When I am trying export another GA4 instance data to BigQuery, the "Link" button at the top right is greyed out.

Because I already exported data one GA4 instance to BigQuery meaning I have correct access role.
I was wondering why I cant do the same for another GA4 instance. Is there restriction that we can connect only one "BigQuery link"? Any help guidance would be appreciated thanks!

I checked access role and BigQuery billing account is also enabled. BigQuery API service is also enabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0xe8.png)

Comment: I didnt found any solution for this issue.. can anyone help me with this. thanks!